# Generating sampling points - making series of points in the horizontal centre of a long polygon, equidistant spacing on vertical axis

Tags: qgis, point, sampling

I have a polygon showing the extent of a beach. I would like to create a series of sampling points along that beach, that are equally spaced north to south (say at increments of 100m to the northing value), and lie in the approximate center of the beach polygon at that northing value.

[image: Sampling points along a beach]

How might I go about this in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will create an equally spaced grid, intersect it's horizontal lines with the beach and calculate centroids of each intersection.

### Steps

1. Use a projected coordinates system (such as UTM).
2. *Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid*

   - Grid type: Line
   - Grid extent: [...] "Use Canvas Extent" or "Use Layer Extent..."
   - Vertical spacing: 100
     [image: screenshot of QGIS Create Grid dialogue]
3. Select by Expression `y_min($geometry) = y_max($geometry)` to select horizontal lines
   [image: screenshot of QGIS Select by Expression, selecting all horizontal lines]
4. *Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersection*

   - Input Layer: Grid ([x] "Selected features only")
   - Overlay layer: beach
     [image: screenshot of QGIS Intersection dialogue]
5. *Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids*
   [image: screenshot of QGIS Centroids dialogue]

### Result

[image: a narrow polygon with equally spaced points]